# Filter one column by matching to another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a variable containing elements to drop if they match to an element in another variable - see a small example below:

```r
df <- data.frame(pair = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 animal = rep(c("dog", "cat"), 3), 
                 value = seq(1, 12, 2), 
                 drop = c("no", "no", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat"))

  pair animal value drop
1    1    dog     1   no
2    1    cat     3   no
3    2    dog     5  dog
4    2    cat     7  dog
5    3    dog     9  cat
6    3    cat    11  cat
```

I'm trying to want to filter the data frame according to whether the value of `animal` matches the value of `drop`. I want something like `filter(df, animal != drop)` to remove rows where only the value of animal matches the value of drop:

```r
  pair animal value drop
1    1    dog     1   no
2    1    cat     3   no
4    2    cat     7  dog
5    3    dog     9  cat
```

I also tried writing a simple loop to test whether animal matches drop for each row and remove the row if true, but I couldn't get it working. (I'm not very confident with loops and would prefer not to use one if possible as my data frame is very large but I was getting desperate!)

```r
for(i in nrow(df)){
  if(df$animal[i] == df$drop[i]){
    df <- df[-i,]
    return(df)
  }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this using dplyr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `filter(df, animal != drop)` is correct. However, as you haven't specified `stringsAsFactors = F` in your `data.frame()` call, all strings are converted to factors, raising the error of different level sets. Thus adding `stringsAsFactors = F`, should solve this

```
df <- data.frame(pair = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 animal = rep(c("dog", "cat"), 3), 
                 value = seq(1, 12, 2), 
                 drop = c("no", "no", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F) 

df %>%
  filter(animal != drop)

  pair animal value drop
1    1    dog     1   no
2    1    cat     3   no
3    2    cat     7  dog
4    3    dog     9  cat
```

To avoid issues with this undesired string to factor behaviour I highly recommend the use of `tibble`

In case that one does not have the opportunity to change how the data is created I here include @akrun's solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(animal, drop), as.character) %>%       
  filter(animal != drop)
#  pair animal value drop
#1    1    dog     1   no
#2    1    cat     3   no
#3    2    cat     7  dog
#4    3    dog     9  cat
```

Comment: This is a good solution in this example, but consider cases where you don't have control over how the data frame is being created. In my daily work, I rarely create data frames like this—my work would be easier if I did! Maybe you can add in how you would deal with the fact that this is currently a factor

Comment: That was my issue, thank you - my original data frame is a tibble but I hadn't considered that one of my variables was factor class. `filter(animal != as.character(drop)` worked perfectly without having to remove the factors.

Comment: Added @akrun`s solution

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to convert to `character` class with `mutate_at` and then use `filter` on non-matching elements

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(animal, drop), as.character) %>%       
  filter(animal != drop)
#  pair animal value drop
#1    1    dog     1   no
#2    1    cat     3   no
#3    2    cat     7  dog
#4    3    dog     9  cat
```