# Filter one column and matching to another (expanded)

Tags: r, filter

Hi I have a similar question to this ([Filter one column by matching to another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345162/filter-one-column-by-matching-to-another-column))

For background I'm trying to match up a code for a book name and a place where it is being used. I figured out how to use filter and grepyl to narrow down the book name but now I need to filter out if the location names match. I can't give up the data since it's private. It's a similar example to the one above except I'm filtering with what the animal starts with first so imagine this.

```
df <- data.frame(pair = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4,4,4),
         animal = rep(c("Elephant", "Giraffe", "Antelope"), 6), 
         value = seq(1, 12, 2), 
         drop = c("savannah", "savannah", "jungle", "jungle", "zoo", "unknown", "unknown", "zoo", "my house"))
         
zoo_animals <- filter(df, grepl("Gir|Ele", animal))
```

what I'm not sure how to do is to build on that to see if the location column matches between each entry. Is it just  & location = location?

What I want is to have it find is there an elephant and a giraffe from the zoo? what about the savanna? From the data I made it appears the only match is savanna so it would print those data points so a df that is

| pair | animal | value | drop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Elephant | 7 | savannah |
| 1 | Giraffe | 3 | savannah |
| 1 | Giraffe | 3 | savannah |

Comment: Oh right sorry!

I copied it straight in:

Comment: You can update your post by `Edit`ing.   Please include the expected as well

Comment: updated! Thank you.